# python3 selenium как вытащить текст?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

изучать selenium начал недавно и еще новичок помогите пожалуйста вот элемент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и мне нужно чтобы в cmd просто вывелось 5 баллов

Answer (score 1):

```
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('do-task').text
print(content)
```

если вам понадобится однозначно идендитифицировать элемент (если элементов с класслом do-task на странице у вас много), то посмотрите в сторону find_element_by_css_selector и find_element_by_xpath [Хоошая статья на хабре про селениум на эту тему](https://habr.com/ru/post/250975/)

[image] А вот так, при помощи инспектора Google Chrome, можно легко получить xpatch путь до любого элемента.

Comment: @nn111666000 Прошу прощения, отвлекся на ответ ниже. fa-star тут не подойдет как идентификатор, так как текст лежит не в теге "i", а в теге "a". Поправил код в примере.